# Outlook added empty space to end of the string

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I try to add outlook contact items using code. But when i try to add phone numbers (Business, mobile) it added extra empty space to end of the string. But it gets correct string when assigning.

See the image[image: empty character added].

Comment: Quick test... Maybe... Set the MobileTelephoneNumber to something even smaller. "+123456" and see if it adds spaces to fill up what I am guessing may be a fixed width property?

Comment: @Mikanikal thanks for the reply. Is it outlook behavior? I added  "+123456"  and try it added  "+1 23456"

Comment: While your results would suggest that it is outlook behavior, I cannot confirm or deny that it should be expected. It's quite possibly trying to conform the phone number to a standardized format. What format that is, I am not sure. Try to do a little research into that property, run a few more tests with other values and see how it may have formats to use or formats that it will convert values into...

Comment: @Mikanikal , I'll try with different test. Thanks !